# Populating POCO object with values from related entity that might be null for populating a string

Tags: entity-framework

Im populating a POCO which I use to return to the caller for use with binding to controls, displaying on a web form etc.  If one of the entities is null, then trying to read one of its related entity values will cause an exception.

Its fields such as "DestinationState", which is nullable in the DB, but my POCO class defines it as a string, which you can not define as nullable.  So in my case, I use a little test on each of those potential problems and set it to empty string.

Below is how im handling it.  This works, but seems like there should be a better way?

```
        OrderInfo retval = new OrderInfo();

        //find order
        Order o = ctx.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderId == oid).First();
        if (o != null)
        {
            //now find the locations
            Location oloc = o.Locations.Where(b => b.OrderKey == o.OrderId).Where(c => c.LocationType.TypeName == "Origin").FirstOrDefault();
            Location dloc = o.Locations.Where(b => b.OrderKey == o.OrderId).Where(c => c.LocationType.TypeName == "Destination").FirstOrDefault();


            retval.CreatedBy = o.User.UserName;
            retval.AccountName = o.Account.AccountName;
            retval.CustomerName = o.CustomerName;
            retval.OfficeName = o.Office.OfficeName;
            retval.DateCreated = o.DateCreated;
            retval.OriginCity = oloc.City == null ? "" : oloc.City;
            retval.OriginState = oloc.State == null ? "" : oloc.State.StateName;
            retval.OriginCountry = oloc.Country == null ? "" : oloc.Country.CountryName;
            retval.AccountRef = o.AccountRefNumber;
            retval.DestinationCity = dloc.City == null ? "" : dloc.City;
            retval.DestinationState = dloc.State == null ? "" : dloc.State.StateName;
            retval.DestinationCountry = dloc.Country == null ? "" : dloc.Country.CountryName;

        }

        return retval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shorthand like this (as long as you are not accessing navigation properties):

```
retval.OriginCity = oloc.City ?? string.Empty;
```

You can also make it cleaner by storing values accessed repeatedly in variables, and using an object initializer:

```
    //find order
    Order o = ctx.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderId == oid).First();
    if (o != null)
    {
        //now find the locations
        Location oloc = o.Locations.Where(b => b.OrderKey == o.OrderId).Where(c => c.LocationType.TypeName == "Origin").FirstOrDefault();
        Location dloc = o.Locations.Where(b => b.OrderKey == o.OrderId).Where(c => c.LocationType.TypeName == "Destination").FirstOrDefault();

        // Store variables that will be used repeatedly
        string cityName = oloc.City ?? string.Empty;
        string stateName = dloc.State == null ? string.Empty : dloc.State.StateName;
        string countryName = dloc.Country == null ? string.Empty : dloc.Country.CountryName;

        // Create object using object initializer and return
        return new OrderInfo {
            CreatedBy = o.User.UserName;
            AccountName = o.Account.AccountName;
            CustomerName = o.CustomerName;
            OfficeName = o.Office.OfficeName;
            DateCreated = o.DateCreated;
            OriginCity = cityName;
            OriginState = stateName;
            OriginCountry = countryName;
            AccountRef = o.AccountRefNumber;
            DestinationCity = cityName;
            DestinationState = stateName;
            DestinationCountry = countryName;
        };
    }
    else 
    {
        return new OrderInfo();
    }
```